# How to fix: Failed to start default target: Transaction for grafical.target/start is destructive with BTRFS errors?

Tags: usb, software-center, 22.04, live-cd, btrfs

After installing Linux Ubuntu 22.04 on usb-stick some applications did not work (for example: “Ubuntu Software”).

I tried reinstalling this app with this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/9pq7in1DTe8

But nothing changed, when I rebooted the system it gave the error along with BTRFS filesystem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Eot.jpg) related errors and froze [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHkPp.jpg).

I then tried to restore the system (both from Linux Ubuntu LiveCD and from initramfs) using instructions from the following sources:
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018769
https://www.linuxshelltips.com/repair-ubuntu-filesystem/

But the system never started. I did not reinstall it.

Please solve this!

Notebook: Asus K501U; USB-flash drive: Kingston Datatravler 3.0 64 gb(here installed the system)(It works fine).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for you, but I just helped a friend with this same issue. The solution was simple. It has to do with a disk not being able to be mounted. In your case in particular, from the photos you posted, you have diagnostic lines saying "BTRFS error (device sdc2).... corrupt 2741...".

That's a clue. That is saying that your hard drive is corrupt and you need to scan and fix it with a LiveCD type of boot media. Once you do that, and you probably already have, then the machine will be able to mount the disk and everything will work.